# Any way to use another name for the external_sdcard folder?

Tags: external-sd, file-system

On my Android tablet, the SD Card is shown as an `external_sdcard` folder, no matter how I rename the card.

Personally I don't like the auto-assigned folder name. Is there a way to use a different default folder name for the SD card, such that the folder name looks more consistent with my other folders?

(Android 4.0.3 WiFi only)

Comment: Do you have a file explorer? If so you could try renaming it from here by long pressing on it. But this may prove to be an issue with mapping to it...

Comment: That would not only require root access, but also break mounting the card (you would need to update the "fstab" as well). Further, that's probably not what ohho had in mind -- he was rather thinking of the LABEL being used as mount-point name (as it is with modern Linux systems for removable data mount points dynamically being created), so it's easy to see *which* card is in the slot.